# Getting SyntaxError against variable

Tags: python

I am a beginner at this course.

I am getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with the following code:

```
class = 8
print(class)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\BISWAJIT\PycharmProjects\NewJourney\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/BISWAJIT/PycharmProjects/NewJourney/Jit.py
File "C:\Users\BISWAJIT\PycharmProjects\NewJourney\Jit.py", line 1
class = 8
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`class` is a Python keyword. It means that this word has a particular meaning for the Python language, and thus cannot be used as a variable name.

Here is the list of keywords, as given by the [`keyword`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html) module:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'async', 'await', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

You can also get it directly from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

You should also note that there is another set of words called *builtins* (full set [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)) for which it is bad practice to use as variable names, although you won't get a `SyntaxError`.

A common way to go around this is either to use `klass` instead of `class`, or add a suffix to the keyword, like in `class_ = 8`. Or you can also find a better naming, depending on the purpose of your variable: `class_number = 8`.